# Reading a file and storing its contents into a 2-D Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I've been trying to create a function that reads a file named "test.txt" and stores its contents into a 2-D array to be used in other functions.

It appears to be reading something from the text file but it only repeats "-9.25996e+61" in the areas where the test.txt numbers should be.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

> the "test.txt" file contains the following 12 elements. They are aligned vertically in the document:

```
70
80
90
75
85
90
60
80
80
90
80
75
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//S is the # of students and T is the number of test scores per student
const int S = 3;
const int T = 4;

void getTests(double[][T]);

int main()
{
    double testScores[S][T];
    getTests(testScores);
}
//*******************
//Gets test scores
void getTests(double testScores[S][T])
{
    ifstream testFile("test.txt");

    double score;

    for (int student = 0; student < S; student++)
    {
        cout << "Student " << student + 1 << endl;
        for (int test = 0; test < T; test++)
        {
            testFile >> score;
            cout << "Test " << test + 1 << endl;
            cout << score << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code's output:

```
Student 1
Test 1
9.25596e+61
Test 2
9.25596e+61
Test 3
9.25596e+61
Test 4
9.25596e+61
Student 2
Test 1
9.25596e+61
Test 2
9.25596e+61
Test 3
9.25596e+61
Test 4
9.25596e+61
Student 3
Test 1
9.25596e+61
Test 2
9.25596e+61
Test 3
9.25596e+61
Test 4
9.25596e+61
```

Comment: First of all, test for `testFile.good()` to see if you opened the file successfully. This is probably your problem.

Comment: I don't think you are reading from the file at all.

Comment: Does not look like `ifstream testFile("test.txt");` succeeds. You must validate whether it does by either checking `testFile.good()` or in validating each read operation `if (!(testFile >> score)) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output suggests your attempt to open your file with `ifstream testFile("test.txt");` fails. You never validate whether the file is open and you fail to validate every read so you have no way of knowing your file never opened.

When handling input, you must ***validate*** every operation. You can do that by validating the stream-state [std::basic_ios](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) provides member functions allowing you to check your stream state through the member functions `.good(), .eof(), .fail() & .bad()`. You should validate the stream state immediately after attempting to open the file. Either explicitly with `.good()` or implicitly by validating that every attempted read from the file succeeds.

In your case you could do:

```
/* read test scores from file 'fname' */
void getTests(double testScores[][T], std::string fname)
{
    std::ifstream testFile (fname); /* open file */
    double score;

    if (!testFile.good()) { /* validate file is open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed - " << fname << '\n';
        return;
    }
```

(**note:** don't hardcode filenames in your code, especially not buried down in a function. Pass the filename as a parameter, or better, open the file in the caller and pass an open file-stream as a parameter after validating the open succeeded in the caller. No need to make the function call to begin with if the file cannot be successfully opened...)

When you read the scores from the file, you must ***validate every read***. You can do this by controlling your read-loop with the result of the read itself. A simple remainder of the `getTests()` function could be:

```
    for (int student = 0; testFile.good() && student < S; student++) {
        int test = 0;
        std::cout << "Student " << student + 1 << '\n';
        while (test < T && testFile >> score) { /* validate EVERY input */
            testScores[student][test] = score;  /* store value in array */
            std::cout << "Test " << ++test << '\n' << score << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Above the read-loop is conditioned upon `test < T` and `testFile >> score`. If your read of `score` fails, your loop exits. Similarly, since you are using nested loops to read a certain number of students, your outer loop only increments while `testFile.good()` remains true.

Putting it altogether, your short example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const int S = 3;    /* number of students */
const int T = 4;    /* number of scores per-student */

void getTests(double[][T], std::string fname);  /* pass filename as parameter */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    double testScores[S][T];
    std::string filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "test.txt";

    getTests (testScores, filename);
}

/* read test scores from file 'fname' */
void getTests(double testScores[][T], std::string fname)
{
    std::ifstream testFile (fname); /* open file */
    double score;

    if (!testFile.good()) { /* validate file is open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed - " << fname << '\n';
        return;
    }

    for (int student = 0; testFile.good() && student < S; student++) {
        int test = 0;
        std::cout << "Student " << student + 1 << '\n';
        while (test < T && testFile >> score) { /* validate EVERY input */
            testScores[student][test] = score;  /* store value in array */
            std::cout << "Test " << ++test << '\n' << score << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the program expects the filename to read from as the 1<sup>st</sup> argument to the program. If no argument is provided, your program will attempt to read from `test.txt` by default. Also **note:** you generally want to avoid including the entire `namespace std` in your code. It's up to you, but it is generally frowned upon.)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/test12elements.txt
70
80
90
75
85
90
60
80
80
90
80
75
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/studentscores dat/test12elements.txt
Student 1
Test 1
70
Test 2
80
Test 3
90
Test 4
75
Student 2
Test 1
85
Test 2
90
Test 3
60
Test 4
80
Student 3
Test 1
80
Test 2
90
Test 3
80
Test 4
75
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Additionally, instead of storing the scores in a plain-old-array of `double`, consider using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You can even create a short struct or `std::unordered_set` to allow you to store the student name along with the array or vector of test scores.

Comment: I'm sure this would work and I can see why it would but I still have an issue opening the file. It always results in an error when testing the file. I even followed your example exactly and it still didn't work. The file is within the resource files of my Visual Studio project. I'll keep trying and hopefully get it tomorrow. I'll post the working code if I ever do.

Comment: (1) are you using an IDE? (2) if so, I suspect you are having a path problem. If you are using the command line, then you can specify the path on the command line. Let me know which and we can work through the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I placed the test.txt file into the "resource files" folder on the right side. It's still only going through the if statement where it would tell the user that there was an error opening the file. I'm also using some examples that my professor gave us when we first learned about files weeks ago.

Comment: Good, you have VS2017. See [How to Pass Command Line Arguments using Visual Studio ?](https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-using-visual-studio/). You have another option. In the VS2017 menu folder, open the `VS Developers Command Prompt`. This gives you the complete freedom of a command line for VS2017. Now simply `cd \Users\you\path\to\your\project` and put your `test.txt` there. Then simply run `nameofproject.exe` test.txt` and it will find your file. This is why I hate IDEs for new programmers. You are not stuck on C, you are stuck on `How do I configure VS?`

Comment: (sorry for the delay, my daughter was playing League and a spurious IPv6 packet locked the router -- with 2 routers (smart switches), a WLAN/wifi router and 3 hubs it took a white to figure out which was locked....)

Comment: Okay, I'll definitely try this tomorrow when I've the time. I don't mind the delay. I'm just glad to have some help. And the Visual Studio IDE is a pain sometimes.

Comment: The file should probably be in the same folder as your project. The default debugging settings set the working directory to $(ProjectDir)

Comment: It indeed was a problem with the file's path. It had to be placed in the source directory and not in the reference.

Comment: Good deal. Glad you got it working. IDEs are nice, but often they can frustrate simple tasks by requiring you to navigate 3+ levels of nested dialogs just to find the correct place to add an argument for your program, or struggling to write a `launch.vs.json` file to pass them. MS did a good job including the `VS Developers Command Prompt` as part of the package. You can compile and run any program you like without having to worry with setting up a project, etc.. (and you learn what compiler options you actually need and how to use them). Then you can tell the IDE what to do.